# CurrencyTextWatcher for currency with symbol in the end

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

In using a pretty standard text watcher:

```
    @Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    EditText editText = editTextWeakReference.get();
    if (editText == null) return;
    String s = editable.toString();
    editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    String cleanString = StringUtils.cleanString(s);
    BigDecimal parsed = new BigDecimal(cleanString).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR).divide(new BigDecimal(100), BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
    String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(myLocale).format(parsed);
    editText.setText(formatted);
    editText.setSelection(formatted.length());
    editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
}
```

I have a problem with currency where symbol in the end. For example 5.50€. Text in EditText doesn't changes when I'm trying to delete. I know what happening, instead of deleting last digit I deleting currency symbol. Then clean string, do changes, and again format string to my Locale.
How can I fix this? How can I clean string before afterTextChanged method?
TextWatcher documentation says it is an error to change CharSequence in beforeTextChanged and onTextChanged.

> Solution has been found. Maybe not the best, but it works. Works as with currencies, where currency symbol before digits , and with currencies, where currency symbol after digits.

```
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    stringLengthBeforeChanges = s.length();
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    EditText editText = editTextWeakReference.get();
    if (editText == null) return;
    String s = editable.toString();
    stringLengthAfterChanges = s.length();
    editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    String cleanString = StringUtils.cleanString(s);
    //this logic block used to correct removal digits when currency symbol after digits
    if(stringLengthBeforeChanges > stringLengthAfterChanges && !isLastCharacterDigit && cleanString.length() > 0){
        cleanString = cleanString.substring(0, cleanString.length()-1);
    }
    BigDecimal value;
    if(cleanString != null){
        value = cleanString.length() == 0 ? BigDecimal.ZERO : new BigDecimal(cleanString);
    } else {
        value = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    }
    BigDecimal parsed = value.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR).divide(new BigDecimal(100), BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
    String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(myLocale).format(parsed);
    editText.setText(formatted);
    editText.setSelection(formatted.length());
    editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
}
```